# date range search with respect to number of chunk size

Tags: java

I wanted to do a date range search in java suppose I wanted to search from 10-22-2019 to the present date.
But the question is to do the date range search in the chunk size of two weeks(consider this can vary but in form weeks)  for eg here start date will 10-22-2019 but the end date will start date + 2 weeks added to it after the date range search is done for this and taking the result. Now the new start date should be were the previous date range search ended. and the end date should be now 2 weeks from the new start date again the search and this keeps on until I get till the present date.

```
 public static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>> SplitDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, int dayChunkSize)
    {
        DateTime chunkEnd;
        while ((chunkEnd = start.AddDays(dayChunkSize)) < end)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(start, chunkEnd);
            start = chunkEnd;
        }
        yield return Tuple.Create(start, end);
    }
```

Got this from one of the answers but have trouble in implementing in my situtation.

Comment: The code you've posted is `C#` code, not java code. Also, it never updates the start date, only the end one, yielding chunks that are 2 weeks wider that the previous

Comment: Ya i Know that's why written having problem in implementing in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple iterative solution :

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("2019-10-22");
LocalDate end = LocalDate.now();


LocalDate chunckStart = start;

while (chunckStart.plusDays(15).isBefore(end)) {
    doTheThing(chunckStart, chunckStart.plusDays(15));
    chunckStart = chunckStart.plusDays(16);
}

doTheThing(chunckStart, end);
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/T44iWX).

Comment: LocalDate.parse("2019-10-22") throws java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '11/14/2019' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: @shyamal you used `LocalDate.parse("11/14/2019")` didn't you? `LocalDate.parse(String datestring)` parses ISO-8601 formatted dates when it's called without other arguments, but you could use [LocalDate.parse(String datestring, DateTimeFormatter formatter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) to specify a DateTimeFormatter that would properly parse your format, or use `LocalDate.of(...)` as in the other answers

Answer (score 0):

try:

```java
    public static Iterator<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>> splitDataRange(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, int dayChunkSize) {
        return new Iterator<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>>() {

            private LocalDate chunkStart = start;

            private LocalDate chunkEnd = start.plusDays(dayChunkSize);

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return end.compareTo(chunkEnd) > 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate> next() {
                Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate> chunk = new Pair<>(chunkStart, chunkEnd);
                chunkStart = chunkEnd;
                chunkEnd = chunkEnd.plusDays(dayChunkSize);
                return chunk;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Iterator<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate>> periodIterator = splitDataRange(LocalDate.of(2019, 3, 1),
                LocalDate.of(2019, 5, 1), 20);

        while (periodIterator.hasNext()) {
            Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate> startEnd = periodIterator.next();
            System.out.println(String.format("from %s to %s"
            , startEnd.getValue0(), startEnd.getValue1()));
        }
    }
```

The `Pair` api is from:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
      <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Streams and `LocalDate`:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 28);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.now();
int step = 7;

start
    .datesUntil(end, Period.ofDays(step))
    .map(date -> {
        LocalDate proposedEnd = date.plusDays(step);
        LocalDate chunkEnd = proposedEnd.compareTo(end) > 0 ? end : proposedEnd;
        return new SimpleEntry<>(date, chunkEnd);
    })
    .forEach(chunk -> System.out.println(chunk.getKey() + " until " + chunk.getValue()));
```

It generates the same output as [the corresponding C# program](https://tio.run/##jVJfa8IwEH9uPsWxp4pdcd3DNnTCqDKE7WUKe47pTcNiKkk66aSf3V3i6lQ2GBTSu9z9/rXCXorS4G5XWakXMK2tw1WfHVdpXiqFwslS2/QRNRop@owJxa2FabnC3L@xLWPRuporKcA67uiQ2sEzlzrusGjLomjEHc7kCv29cXAPGjfQNuOsl/USyOi57fSPp1EXv89eJ3AXRj0RKV3T2A0pi6IPbsCgpXq6VtL5vReuFxgH5sRDJmEjrL9RAFwsIZ5Va4WDliU58A3BkBmPSE6ClSinMEqF6auRDp@kxtikEwrrCrpwAZV2UtHZhX03CzyNl2bQVUZDjxpUw1lkk7GuVmj4nHT8qWZ47uo02J/JvU@fTsHrfFnp96n8xPOvIfzFWBde4mYpFUIctz1KMGCmD0Ux4rWNT4A6MPAUh1BqiaqAb4dBfppTtO6Qewsb4oja3@BYQMP@AYN7hIY1u90X).

---

The `datesUntil` method requires Java 9. Otherwise, if you're using Java 8, then you could use a helper method instead:

```
public static Stream<LocalDate> datesUntil(LocalDate from, LocalDate toExclusive) {
    long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(from, toExclusive);
    return Stream.iterate(from, t -> t.plusDays(1))
        .limit(daysBetween);
    }
```